Wordpress 6.6.1 - Trying to make a block but receive error, "! Cannot read property 'then' of undefined"
I am following this post.  In the very first command I get an err
npx @wordpress/create-block@latest todo-list

npm ERR! Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/example/.npm/_logs/2024-07-25T10_00_18_279Z-debug-0.log
someuser@someserver:~/htdocs/example.com/wp-content/plugins$ npx @wordpress/create-block@latest todo-list
npm ERR! Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/someuser/.npm/_logs/2024-07-25T10_07_52_541Z-debug-0.log

The content of the error log is;
0 verbose cli [
0 verbose cli   '/usr/bin/node',
0 verbose cli   '/usr/share/nodejs/npm/bin/npm-cli.js',
0 verbose cli   'exec',
0 verbose cli   '--',
0 verbose cli   '@wordpress/create-block@latest',
0 verbose cli   'todo-list'
0 verbose cli ]
1 info using npm@8.5.1
2 info using node@v12.22.9
3 timing npm:load:whichnode Completed in 0ms
4 timing config:load:defaults Completed in 3ms
5 timing config:load:file:/usr/share/nodejs/npm/npmrc Completed in 3ms
6 timing config:load:builtin Completed in 3ms
7 timing config:load:cli Completed in 1ms
8 timing config:load:env Completed in 1ms
9 timing config:load:file:/home/someuser/htdocs/example.com/wp-content/plugins/.npmrc Completed in 0ms
10 timing config:load:project Completed in 1ms
11 timing config:load:file:/home/someuser/.npmrc Completed in 0ms
12 timing config:load:user Completed in 0ms
13 timing config:load:file:/etc/npmrc Completed in 0ms
14 timing config:load:global Completed in 0ms
15 timing config:load:validate Completed in 0ms
16 timing config:load:credentials Completed in 1ms
17 timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 1ms
18 timing config:load Completed in 12ms
19 timing npm:load:configload Completed in 12ms
20 timing npm:load:setTitle Completed in 0ms
21 timing config:load:flatten Completed in 3ms
22 timing npm:load:display Completed in 5ms
23 verbose logfile /home/someuser/.npm/_logs/2024-07-25T10_07_52_541Z-debug-0.log
24 timing npm:load:logFile Completed in 5ms
25 timing npm:load:timers Completed in 0ms
26 timing npm:load:configScope Completed in 0ms
27 timing npm:load Completed in 23ms
28 verbose stack TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
28 verbose stack     at /usr/share/nodejs/cacache/lib/util/fix-owner.js:113:7
29 verbose cwd /home/someuser/htdocs/example.com/wp-content/plugins
30 verbose Linux 5.15.0-91-generic
31 verbose argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/share/nodejs/npm/bin/npm-cli.js" "exec" "--" "@wordpress/create-block@latest" "todo-list"
32 verbose node v12.22.9
33 verbose npm  v8.5.1
34 error Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
35 verbose exit 1
36 timing npm Completed in 1190ms
37 verbose unfinished npm timer command:exec 1721902072737
38 verbose code 1
39 error A complete log of this run can be found in:
39 error     /home/someuser/.npm/_logs/2024-07-25T10_07_52_541Z-debug-0.log

Appreciate any help please.
Is the below to be run as sudo or root?
npx @wordpress/create-block@latest todo-list

if I run as sudo I get this error
sudo npx @wordpress/create-block@latest 
sh: 1: wp-create-block: Permission denied

root is the same.
Any ideas anyone?

I know you've linked to a tutorial, but you would need to share the relevant bits of code for someone to be able to help track this down. There is no "then" on the tutorial page so there must be one somewhere in your code that comes immediately after the problem element.

@webelaine  that "then" is core wordpress and not my code.  I simply run the very first line of the tutorial and it is already giving an error.  Youl want to start copying code from wordpress core?

Have you tried using a more recent version of Node or NPM? The command runs for me with Node 20.11.0 and NPM 10.2.4. If those versions don't also work for you, I would suspect a permissions issue since you're getting a different result with sudo. Normally it's best to sort out file ownership and permissions rather than using sudo.
